# PHP web apps are to Laravel, as Objective-C iPhone apps are to.. what?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I wouldn't dream of beginning a PHP web development project without a framework. At the moment the framework of choice is Laravel.

Are there similar options for Objective-C?

My attempts at Googling for it tend to bring back information about cross-platform browser-based frameworks.

Comment: There are a bunch of frameworks depending on what you are trying to achieve - Cocoa is the core of iOS apps but there are also SpriteKit, SceneKit, Core Data, Core Bluetooth, Metal, AVFoundation...

Comment: Yes, they're the frameworks that are part of the Cocoa ecosystem. They don't quite seem to have the relationship that exists between PHP and Laravel though. I suppose what I'm seeking out is something that provides the same starting point of how to structure your application. Perhaps the wide scope of what an iOS app can do prevents that same kind of relationship from being applicable.

Comment: I don't think you will find an equivalent.  As you say, iOS apps have much wider scope than a web site.  Much of the core functionality of many web sites is the same - maintain membership, authenticate users, grant access/permissions, retrieve/update data and so on - even if one website is a social network and another is an online-store.  iOS apps are more varied which is why there are frameworks for games, frameworks for data management, frameworks for UI, frameworks for networking and so on.  Cocoa provides the basic structure for an app - App Delegate, view controllers etc